# On deploying Script to enable Customer Managed Key in Azure Data Factory using terraform, I am getting an error which I have stated below

Tags: terraform, azure-data-factory, terraform-provider-azure

On trying to use this code snippet to enable customer managed key I am not being able to proceed with terraform plan itself. I tried few methods but even they did not work. Can anyone please help me resolve this issue??
**

```
'''
    data "azurerm_client_config" "current" {}
    resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
      name     = "testadfrg"
      location = "West Europe"
    }
    resource "azurerm_key_vault" "example" {
      name                       = "testkeyvault"
      location                   = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
      resource_group_name        = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
      tenant_id                  = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
      sku_name                   = "standard"
      soft_delete_retention_days = 7
      access_policy {
        tenant_id = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
        object_id = data.azurerm_client_config.current.object_id
        key_permissions = [
          "create",
          "get",
          "purge",
          "recover"
        ]
        secret_permissions = [
          "set",
        ]
      }
    }
    resource "azurerm_key_vault_key" "generated" {
      name         = "adfkey"
      key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.example.id
      key_type     = "RSA"
      key_size     = 2048
      key_opts = [
        "decrypt",
        "encrypt",
        "sign",
        "unwrapKey",
        "verify",
        "wrapKey",
      ]
    }
    resource "azurerm_data_factory" "df" {
      name                    = "testadfadf"
      location                = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
      resource_group_name     = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
      public_network_enabled  = "true"
      customer_managed_key_id = azurerm_key_vault_key.generated.id
      identity {
        type = "SystemAssigned"
      }
    }
'''
```

**

[image]

Comment: Please refrain from pasting screenshots of text. Instead, copy-paste it directly in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a user assigned identity for ADF to have access to Keyvault. Then , create a access policy for the that user assigned identity in Keyvault and then finally while creating ADF you have to use below :

```
identity {
        type = "UserAssigned"
        identity_ids = [azurerm_user_assigned_identity.base.id]
      }
```

Instead of

```
identity {
        type = "SystemAssigned"
      }
```

So, your overall code will be something like below:

```
provider "azurerm" {
    features{}
}
data "azurerm_client_config" "current" {}

data "azurerm_resource_group" "example"{
    name = "yourresourcegroupname"
}

resource "azurerm_user_assigned_identity" "base" {
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  name                = "mi-adf-keyvault"
}


resource "azurerm_key_vault" "kv" {
  name                       = "ansumankeyvault01"
  location                   = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name        = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  tenant_id = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
  sku_name = "standard"
  access_policy {
    object_id    = data.azurerm_client_config.current.object_id
    tenant_id    = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id

    certificate_permissions = [
      "Create",
      "Delete",
      "DeleteIssuers",
      "Get",
      "GetIssuers",
      "Import",
      "List",
      "ListIssuers",
      "ManageContacts",
      "ManageIssuers",
      "Purge",
      "SetIssuers",
      "Update"
    ]

    key_permissions = [
      "Backup",
      "Create",
      "Decrypt",
      "Delete",
      "Encrypt",
      "Get",
      "Import",
      "List",
      "Purge",
      "Recover",
      "Restore",
      "Sign",
      "UnwrapKey",
      "Update",
      "Verify",
      "WrapKey"
    ]

    secret_permissions = [
      "Backup",
      "Delete",
      "Get",
      "List",
      "Purge",
      "Restore",
      "Restore",
      "Set"
    ]
  }

  access_policy {
    object_id    = azurerm_user_assigned_identity.base.principal_id
    tenant_id    = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id

    secret_permissions = [
      "Get"
    ]
    
    key_permissions = [
        "Get",
        "decrypt",
        "encrypt",
        "sign",
        "unwrapKey",
        "verify",
        "wrapKey",
    ]

    certificate_permissions = [
        "Get"
    ]
  }
}

resource "azurerm_key_vault_key" "generated" {
  name         = "generated-certificate"
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.kv.id
  key_type     = "RSA"
  key_size     = 2048

  key_opts = [
    "decrypt",
    "encrypt",
    "sign",
    "unwrapKey",
    "verify",
    "wrapKey",
  ]
}
resource "null_resource" "previous" {}

resource "time_sleep" "wait_120_seconds" {
  depends_on = [azurerm_key_vault.kv]

  create_duration = "120s"
}
resource "azurerm_data_factory" "df" {
      name                    = "ansumantestadf" #uniquename
      location                = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
      resource_group_name     = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
      public_network_enabled  = "true"
      customer_managed_key_id = azurerm_key_vault_key.generated.id
      identity {
        type = "UserAssigned"
        identity_ids = [azurerm_user_assigned_identity.base.id]
      }
      depends_on = [time_sleep.wait_120_seconds]
}
```

**Note:** I have used time sleep block as it might take some time for the access policy to reflect in the key vault for user assigned identity.

**Outputs:**

[image]

[image]